# grunt-contrib-jade unable to read file (EISDIR)

Tags: gruntjs, pug, grunt-contrib-jade

Executing `grunt jade:dev` on this

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    "jade": {
        "dev": {
            "files": {
                "cwd": "src",
                "src": ["**/*.jade"],
                "dest": "dist",
                "ext": ".html",
                "expand": true
            },
            "options": {
                "pretty": true,
                "data": {
                    "environment": "dev"
                }
            }
        },
        "prod": {
            "files": {
                "cwd": "src",
                "src": ["**/*.jade"],
                "dest": "dist",
                "ext": ".html",
                "expand": true
            },
            "options": {
                "pretty": true,
                "data": {
                    "environment": "prod"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

fails with

> Warning: Unable to read "src" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.

But executing `grunt jade` on this

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    "jade": {
        "files": {
            "cwd": "src",
            "src": ["**/*.jade"],
            "dest": "dist",
            "ext": ".html",
            "expand": true
        },
        "options": {
            "pretty": true,
            "data": {
                "environment": "dev"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

succeeds.

There is no difference between the configuration of the tasks I'm running in both cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this seems to work:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    "jade": {
        "dev": {
            "cwd": "src",
            "src": ["**/*.jade"],
            "dest": "dist",
            "ext": ".html",
            "expand": true,
            "options": {
                "pretty": true,
                "data": {
                    "environment": "dev"
                }
            }
        },
        "prod": {
            "cwd": "src",
            "src": ["**/*.jade"],
            "dest": "dist",
            "ext": ".html",
            "expand": true,
            "options": {
                "pretty": true,
                "data": {
                    "environment": "prod"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

All I did was remove the enclosing `"files"` object.